# Changing the connection string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssis, ssis-2012

We deployed the packages from an old server to a new server. How to change the connection string i.e initial catalog or server name parameter from `Agent job -> Configuration -> Connection manager`? Is there a possibility to do it from here?

I'm receiving the below error if I'm changing the data source and servername.

[image]

Comment: In the future, you can consider using environment variables, that are stored in the catalog and point your packages to use them for the server names. That way you can easily change the server names for lots of packages\projects at once, or easily manage deployments from dev to prod, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After SSIS package deployed to new environment still it may use old connection string.

> how to change the connection string i.e initial catalog or server name
>   parameter from Agent job > configuration > connection manger .Is there
>   a possibility to do from here ?

Yes, It's possible when you are `sysadmin` and you can change manually by following:

> Right click on AgentJob -> Properties -> Job step -> Configuration ->
>   Connection Managers
>
> Below Connection Managers -> select Name of database then on
>   properties ->
>
> - `Connectionstring -> Data Source=yourServerName;InitialCatalog=Databasename;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;IntegratedSecurity
>     = SSPI;Auto Translate=False;` (you can edit Data source and intial catalog manually)
>
> and
>
> - `Servername = 'yourservername'`